# Python websocket sql Is there any way without having to write a billion of 'if...elif'?

Tags: python, sql, json, if-statement, websocket

I'm writing a websocket API to get real time data from a data provider and update my own database. The data is in JSON format. The mechanism is that the first time the program send a request to their server it will return a JSON format data which includes all the fields. And as long as the connection is alive, once there is a change in a particular field(s), the server will send a JSON format data back to me which only includes the fields that changes.
Therefore, my sql statment will have to cater to all the secenarios using if or switch cases.
But there're too many possible combinations. Is there any way to do this without having to write a billion of 'if...elif'? Thank you.

Example JSON data for when I made the request for the first time(which includes all the fields):

```
[
{
  "Fields":{
    "ACTIV_DATE":"2023-08-22",
    "ACT_FLAG1":" ",
    "ACT_FLAG2":" ",
    "ACT_FLAG3":" ",
    "ACT_TP_1":"B\u21e7",
    "ACT_TP_2":"B\u21e7",
    "ACT_TP_3":"B\u21e7",
    "ACVOL_1":null,
    "ASIA_CLOSE":null,
    "ASIA_CL_DT":null,
    "ASIA_HIGH":null,
    "ASIA_HI_TM":null,
    "ASIA_LOW":null,
    "ASIA_LW_TM":null,
    "ASIA_NETCH":null,
    "ASIA_OPEN":null,
    "ASIA_OP_TM":null,
    "ASK":7.2929,
    "ASKSIZE":null,
    "ASK_1":7.2925,
    "ASK_2":7.2885,
    "ASK_HIGH_1":7.2932,
    "ASK_HI_TME":"08:26:00",
    "ASK_LOW_1":7.268,
    "ASK_LO_TME":"01:34:00",
    "ASK_SPREAD":null,
    "BCAST_REF":"CNY=",
    "BCKGRNDPAG":"    ",
    "BEST_ASIZ1":null,
    "BEST_ASIZ2":null,
    "BEST_ASIZ3":null,
    "BEST_ASIZ4":null,
    "BEST_ASIZ5":null,
    "BEST_ASK1":null,
    "BEST_ASK2":null,
    "BEST_ASK3":null,
    "BEST_ASK4":null,
    "BEST_ASK5":null,
    "BEST_BID1":null,
    "BEST_BID2":null,
    "BEST_BID3":null,
    "BEST_BID4":null,
    "BEST_BID5":null,
    "BEST_BSIZ1":null,
    "BEST_BSIZ2":null,
    "BEST_BSIZ3":null,
    "BEST_BSIZ4":null,
    "BEST_BSIZ5":null,
    "BID":7.2923,
    "BIDSIZE":null,
    "BID_1":7.2911,
    "BID_2":7.2882,
    "BID_HIGH_1":7.2926,
    "BID_LOW_1":7.267,
    "BID_NET_CH":0.0058,
    "BID_SPREAD":null,
    "BID_TICK_1":"\u21e7",
    "BKGD_REF":"Chinese Yuan",
    "BOND_TYPE":"   ",
    "BPV":null,
    "B_ASK1_TIM":null,
    "B_ASK2_TIM":null,
    "B_ASK3_TIM":null,
    "B_ASK4_TIM":null,
    "B_ASK5_TIM":null,
    "B_BID1_TIM":null,
    "B_BID2_TIM":null,
    "B_BID3_TIM":null,
    "B_BID4_TIM":null,
    "B_BID5_TIM":null,
    "CALL_PRC":null,
    "CCY_NAME":"                              ",
    "CLOSE_ASK":7.289,
    "CLOSE_BID":7.2865,
    "CLOSE_TYPE":"B ",
    "CNTCT_ID":null,
    "CONTEXT_ID":3284,
    "CONVEXITY":null,
    "CROSS_SC":"1E+00",
    "CTBLOC_ID1":"   ",
    "CTBLOC_ID2":"   ",
    "CTBLOC_ID3":"   ",
    "CTBTR_1":"Refinitiv",
    "CTBTR_2":"            ",
    "CTBTR_3":"            ",
    "CTBTR_BKGD":null,
    "CTBTR_ID1":"    ",
    "CTBTR_ID2":"    ",
    "CTBTR_ID3":"    ",
    "CTB_LOC1":"   ",
    "CTB_LOC2":"   ",
    "CTB_LOC3":"   ",
    "CTB_PAGE1":"    ",
    "CTB_PAGE2":"    ",
    "CTB_PAGE3":"    ",
    "CURRENCY":"CNY",
    "DAYS_MAT":null,
    "DEALT_VL1":null,
    "DEALT_VL2":null,
    "DEALT_VL3":null,
    "DELTA":null,
    "DLG_CODE1":"      ",
    "DLG_CODE2":"      ",
    "DLG_CODE3":"      ",
    "DSO_ID":16416,
    "DSPLY_NAME":"Refinitiv",
    "DVOL1_SC":" ",
    "DVOL2_SC":" ",
    "DVOL3_SC":" ",
    "EMAIL_ADRS":"                                        ",
    "EURO_CLOSE":null,
    "EURO_CL_DT":null,
    "EURO_HIGH":null,
    "EURO_HI_TM":null,
    "EURO_LOW":null,
    "EURO_LW_TM":null,
    "EURO_NETCH":null,
    "EURO_OPEN":null,
    "EURO_OP_TM":null,
    "FIX_DATE":null,
    "FWD1_PRICE":null,
    "FWD2_PRICE":null,
    "GEN_TEXT16":"                ",
    "GEN_VAL1":null,
    "GEN_VAL10":null,
    "GEN_VAL2":null,
    "GEN_VAL3":null,
    "GEN_VAL4":null,
    "GEN_VAL5":null,
    "GEN_VAL6":null,
    "GEN_VAL7":null,
    "GEN_VAL8":null,
    "GEN_VAL9":null,
    "GN_TXT16_2":"                ",
    "GN_TXT24_1":"                        ",
    "GN_TXT32_1":"                                ",
    "GN_TXT32_2":"                                ",
    "GV10_TEXT":"      ",
    "GV1_DATE":null,
    "GV1_FLAG":" ",
    "GV1_TEXT":"SPOT  ",
    "GV1_TIME":null,
    "GV2A_RTIM1":null,
    "GV2A_RTIM2":null,
    "GV2A_RTIM3":null,
    "GV2B_RTIM1":null,
    "GV2B_RTIM2":null,
    "GV2B_RTIM3":null,
    "GV2_DATE":null,
    "GV2_FLAG":" ",
    "GV2_TEXT":"USDCNY",
    "GV2_TIME":null,
    "GV3_FLAG":" ",
    "GV3_TEXT":"      ",
    "GV4_FLAG":" ",
    "GV4_TEXT":"      ",
    "GV5_TEXT":"      ",
    "GV6_TEXT":"      ",
    "GV7_TEXT":"      ",
    "GV8_TEXT":"      ",
    "GV9_TEXT":"      ",
    "HIGHTP_1":"B",
    "HIGH_1":7.2926,
    "HIGH_2":7.2911,
    "HIGH_3":7.2909,
    "HIGH_4":7.2909,
    "HIGH_5":7.2909,
    "HIGH_TIME":"08:26:00",
    "HIGH_TIME2":"08:19:00",
    "HIGH_TIME3":"07:30:00",
    "HIGH_TIME4":"07:30:00",
    "HIGH_TIME5":"07:30:00",
    "HIGH_YLD":null,
    "HSTCLBDDAT":"2023-08-21",
    "HSTCLSDATE":"2023-08-21",
    "HST_CLOSE":7.2865,
    "HST_CLSBID":7.2865,
    "HST_CLSYLD":null,
    "IND_NEWS":"          ",
    "INST_DESC":"                              ",
    "IRGFID":null,
    "IRGPRC":0.0796,
    "IRGVAL":null,
    "LONGLINK1":null,
    "LOWTP_1":"A",
    "LOW_1":7.268,
    "LOW_2":7.268,
    "LOW_3":7.268,
    "LOW_4":7.268,
    "LOW_5":7.268,
    "LOW_TIME":"01:34:00",
    "LOW_TIME2":"01:34:00",
    "LOW_TIME3":"01:34:00",
    "LOW_TIME4":"01:34:00",
    "LOW_TIME5":"01:34:00",
    "LOW_YLD":null,
    "MATUR_DATE":null,
    "MID_1":null,
    "MID_2":null,
    "MID_3":null,
    "MID_NET_CH":null,
    "MID_PRICE":null,
    "MID_SPREAD":null,
    "MONTH_HIGH":null,
    "MONTH_LOW":null,
    "MTD":null,
    "MTHHI_DT":null,
    "MTHLO_DT":null,
    "NETCHNG_1":0.0058,
    "NEWS":"    ",
    "NEWSTM_MS":null,
    "NEWS_TIME":null,
    "NOMINAL":null,
    "NUM_BIDS":null,
    "NUM_MOVES":null,
    "OFFCL_CODE":"MHSH        ",
    "OFFC_CODE2":"            ",
    "OFF_CD_IN2":"   ",
    "OFF_CD_IND":"   ",
    "OPEN_BID":7.267,
    "OPEN_PRC":7.267,
    "OPEN_TIME":"01:34:00",
    "OPEN_TYPE":"B ",
    "OPEN_YLD":null,
    "PCTCHG_3M":null,
    "PCTCHG_6M":null,
    "PCTCHG_INC":null,
    "PCTCHG_MTD":null,
    "PCTCHG_TRT":null,
    "PCTCHG_YTD":null,
    "PCTCHNG":0.08,
    "PREF_DISP":153,
    "PREMIUM":null,
    "PREV_DISP":null,
    "PRIMACT_1":7.2923,
    "PRIMACT_2":7.2911,
    "PRIMACT_3":7.2882,
    "PROD_PERM":363,
    "PROV_SYMB":"                                ",
    "PR_FREQ":"      ",
    "PUTCALLIND":"CALL",
    "P_C_IND1":"    ",
    "QUOTE_TYPE":"   ",
    "QUOTIM_MS":null,
    "RCS_AS_CLA":"   ",
    "RDNDISPLAY":153,
    "RDN_EXCHD2":"NY$",
    "RDN_EXCHID":"   ",
    "RECORDTYPE":209,
    "REL_SPEEDG":null,
    "RIC_DESC":"        ",
    "RT_YIELD_1":null,
    "SALTIM_MS":null,
    "SCALING":"1       ",
    "SC_ACT_TP1":"  ",
    "SC_ACT_TP2":"  ",
    "SC_ACT_TP3":"  ",
    "SC_AFLAG1":" ",
    "SC_AFLAG2":" ",
    "SC_AFLAG3":" ",
    "SEC_ACT_1":7.2929,
    "SEC_ACT_2":7.2925,
    "SEC_ACT_3":7.2885,
    "SEC_HIGH":null,
    "SEC_HI_TP":" ",
    "SEC_LOW":null,
    "SEC_LO_TP":" ",
    "SEC_VOL1":null,
    "SEQNUM":null,
    "SETTLEDATE":null,
    "SPS_SP_RIC":".[SPSEVAI-VAH10-P4",
    "START_DT":null,
    "TERM":null,
    "TIMACT":"08:29:00",
    "TIMCOR":null,
    "TIMCOR_MS":null,
    "TRADE_DATE":null,
    "TRDPRC_1":null,
    "TRDTIM_1":null,
    "TRDTIM_MS":null,
    "TRDVOL_1":null,
    "TRD_UNITS":"4DP ",
    "US_CLOSE":null,
    "US_CL_DT":null,
    "US_HIGH":null,
    "US_HI_TM":null,
    "US_LOW":null,
    "US_LW_TM":null,
    "US_NETCH":null,
    "US_OPEN":null,
    "US_OP_TM":null,
    "VALUE_DT1":"2023-08-22",
    "VALUE_DT2":"2023-08-22",
    "VALUE_DT3":"2023-08-22",
    "VALUE_TS1":"08:29:57",
    "VALUE_TS2":"08:19:04",
    "VALUE_TS3":"08:09:39",
    "WEB_ADRS":"                                                                                ",
    "WEEK_HIGH":null,
    "WEEK_LOW":null,
    "WEIGHTING":null,
    "WKHI_DT":null,
    "WKLO_DT":null,
    "WTD_AVE1":null,
    "YLD_NETCHG":null,
    "YRBDHI_IND":" ",
    "YRBDLO_IND":" ",
    "YRBIDHIGH":7.317,
    "YRBIDLOW":6.6905,
    "YRHIGH":7.317,
    "YRHIGHDAT":null,
    "YRLOW":6.6915,
    "YRLOWDAT":null,
    "YTD":null
  },
  "ID":2,
  "Key":{
    "Name":"CNY=X",
    "Service":"ELEKTRON_DD"
  },
  "PermData":"AwEBNjw=",
  "Qos":{
    "Rate":"JitConflated",
    "Timeliness":"Realtime"
  },
  "SeqNumber":6334,
  "State":{
    "Data":"Ok",
    "Stream":"Open"
  },
  "Type":"Refresh"
}
```

]

Example JSON data for when the server send me the updated data(which only includes the field(s) that changes):

```
 [
  {
    "DoNotConflate":true,
    "Fields":{
      "ACTIV_DATE":"2023-08-22",
      "ACT_TP_2":"B\u21e7",
      "ACT_TP_3":"B\u21e7",
      "ASK":7.292,
      "ASK_HIGH_1":7.2938,
      "ASK_HI_TME":"08:31:00",
      "ASK_LOW_1":7.268,
      "ASK_LO_TME":"01:34:00",
      "BID":7.2908,
      "BID_HIGH_1":7.2933,
      "BID_LOW_1":7.267,
      "BID_NET_CH":0.0043,
      "BID_TICK_1":"\u21e9",
      "CLOSE_ASK":7.289,
      "CLOSE_BID":7.2865,
      "CLOSE_TYPE":"B ",
      "GV2_TEXT":"USDCNY",
      "HIGHTP_1":"B",
      "HIGH_1":7.2933,
      "HIGH_TIME":"08:34:00",
      "HSTCLBDDAT":"2023-08-21",
      "HSTCLSDATE":"2023-08-21",
      "HST_CLOSE":7.2865,
      "HST_CLSBID":7.2865,
      "IRGPRC":0.059,
      "LOWTP_1":"A",
      "LOW_1":7.268,
      "LOW_TIME":"01:34:00",
      "NETCHNG_1":0.0043,
      "OPEN_BID":7.267,
      "OPEN_PRC":7.267,
      "OPEN_TIME":"01:34:00",
      "OPEN_TYPE":"B ",
      "PCTCHNG":0.06,
      "PRIMACT_1":7.2908,
      "SCALING":"1       ",
      "SEC_ACT_1":7.292,
      "TIMACT":"08:39:00",
      "VALUE_DT1":"2023-08-22",
      "VALUE_TS1":"08:39:04",
      "YRBIDHIGH":7.317,
      "YRBIDLOW":6.6905,
      "YRHIGH":7.317,
      "YRLOW":6.6915
    },
    "ID":2,
    "Key":{
      "Name":"CNY=X",
      "Service":"ELEKTRON_DD"
    },
    "SeqNumber":6350,
    "Type":"Update",
    "UpdateType":"Unspecified"
  }
]
```

EDIT:

I tried the mapping method but I get the following error:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

This is the code:

```
 field_map = {
                'TRDPRC_1': 'NominalPrice',
                'NETCHNG_1': 'Net_Change',
                'PCTCHNG': 'Percent_Change',
                'TURNOVER': 'TurnOver',
                'ACVOL_1': 'SharesTrades',
                'ASK': 'Ask_Price',
                'BID': 'Bid_Price',
                'LOT_SIZE': 'LotSize',
                'HIGH_1': 'Today_Highest',
                'LOW_1': 'Today_Lowest',
                'DSPLY_NAME': 'English_Name',
                'DSPLY_NMLL': 'Chinese_Name',
                'PERATIO': 'PERatio',
                'DIVIDEND': 'Dividend',
                '52WK_HIGH': 'Year_Highest',
                '52WK_LOW': 'Year_Lowest'
                
            }
                item_data = {
                v: data["Fields"][k]
                for k, v in field_map
                if k in data["Fields"]
                }
                fields = list(item_data)
                update_sql = ', '.join(f"{field}=?" for field in fields)
                cmd_data = [item_data[field] for field in fields]
                cmd_data.append(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
                cmd_data.append(data['Key']['Name'].lstrip('0').rstrip('.HK'))
                cmd = f"UPDATE myTable SET {update_sql}, ReutersDate=? WHERE Stock_Code=?"
              
                print(cmd)
                print(cmd_data)
                cur2.execute(cmd, cmd_data)
                conn2.commit()
```

Stack trace is as follow:

Exception in thread Thread-2 (process_data):

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\tobywong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()

File "C:\Users\tobywong\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

File "c:\Users\tobywong\Desktop\Refinitiv_RealTimeDataHKStock_API.py", line 58, in process_data

```
item_data = {
            ^
```

File "c:\Users\tobywong\Desktop\Refinitiv_RealTimeDataHKStock_API.py", line 60, in < dictcomp >

```
for k, v in field_map
    ^^^^
```

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your SQL dynamically, no `if` needed. Something like this should work (where `item` is a single element of your update list):

```
fields = list(item["Fields"])
update_sql = ', '.join(f"{field}=%s" for field in fields)
cmd_data = [item["Fields"][field] for field in fields]
cmd_data.append(item["ID"])
cmd = f"UPDATE mytable SET {update_sql} WHERE ID=%s"
cursor.execute(cmd, cmd_data)
```

EDIT: If you need field filtering / mapping, here's what you can do:

```
field_map = {
    "OPEN_BID": "o_bid",
    "CLOSE_BID": "c_bid",
}

item_data = {
    v: item["Fields"][k]
    for k, v in field_map.items()
    if k in item["Fields"]
}
fields = list(item_data)
update_sql = ', '.join(f"{field}=%s" for field in fields)
cmd_data = [item_data[field] for field in fields]
cmd_data.append(item["ID"])
cmd = f"UPDATE mytable SET {update_sql} WHERE ID=%s"
cursor.execute(cmd, cmd_data)
```

This will execute

```
UPDATE mytable SET o_bid=7.267, c_bid=7.2865 WHERE ID=2
```

EDIT: For a second there was a comment asking for a case where one datum should go into several fields. You can modify the code like this:

```
field_map = {
    "OPEN_BID": "o_bid",
    "CLOSE_BID": "c_bid",
    "DSPLY_NAME": ["English_Name", "Reuters_English"],
}

item_data = [
    [col, item["Fields"][k]]
    for k, v in field_map.items()
    for col in (v if isinstance(v, list) else [v])
    if k in item["Fields"]
]
fields, cmd_data = (list(x) for x in zip(*item_data))
update_sql = ', '.join(f"{field}=%s" for field in fields)
cmd_data.append(item["ID"])
cmd = f"UPDATE mytable SET {update_sql} WHERE ID=%s"
cursor.execute(cmd, cmd_data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But there is a problem which is that the fields in the JSON data does not equal to the name of the columns in the database. And also not all the fields in the JSON data are needed. Only like 10 fields are needed. But I really appreciate the response.

Comment: @Tobywkw you could map the JSON keys to the appropriate column name using a dictionary. If this doesn't seem to suite your needs you could probably go for some external package that offers some sort of serialization and an ORM for you.

Comment: Please include the relevant data in the question. I can't read your mind :)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Do you mean creating a dictionary using the JSON key as key and database column name as value? And what do I do after that?

Comment: @Amadan Sorry, I miss that part in my question,.

Comment: @Amadan Thank you so so much and thank you AbdulAzizBarkat too. I will give this a try(it will take me some time). If it works I will come back and mark this as the answer.

Comment: @Amadan I tried it and there is an error. Please see the edited post. Thank you.

Comment: Again, the information you provide is insufficient for me to be certain about anything. Please include the entire error message, including the stack trace, and any additional information that you might have (specifically here the output of `print(cmd); print(cmd_data)`

Comment: @Amadan Please see my edited post. It dosen't get to lines print(cmd) and print(cmd_data) before the program stop due to the error

Comment: Ah, that is my error. It should be `for k, v in field_map.items()`. I will correct the answer.